# OnScroll Event is cycling when scrolled programmicaly inside

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

When I create a Scroll Listener which scrolls to specific position inside, it triggers itself again even when I catch the first recall at the beginning. Idk what could cause this.

```
const Example: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  let _preventScroll = false;
  let _currentParagraph = 0;
  let _lastScrollTop = 0;
  const _paragraphs = [
    useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null),
    useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null),
    useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null),
    useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null),
    useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null),
    useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null),
  ];
  useEffect(() => {
    
    const onScroll = (ev: Event) => {
      if (_preventScroll) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        _preventScroll = false;
        return;
      }

      var st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      if (st > _lastScrollTop && _currentParagraph < 5) {
        _currentParagraph++;
      } else if (_currentParagraph > 0) {
        _currentParagraph--;
      }
      _preventScroll = true;
      _paragraphs[_currentParagraph].current?.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "start",
      });

      _lastScrollTop = st <= 0 ? 0 : st;
    };
    window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
     <div style={{height: "100vh"}} ref={paragraph[0]} />
     <div style={{height: "100vh"}} ref={paragraph[1]} />
     <div style={{height: "100vh"}} ref={paragraph[2]} />
     <div style={{height: "100vh"}} ref={paragraph[3]} />
     <div style={{height: "100vh"}} ref={paragraph[4]} />
    </>  
  );
};

export default Example;
```

I tried to add an Catch of the first recall but after this another happen from nowhere.

May there is a Issue with Bubbling idk.

Comment: Sounds like your are trying to have a state for when scrolling to not fire your event. Did you try the `useState` hook? Also, have a look at this scroll hook: https://github.com/n8tb1t/use-scroll-position that might simplify your logic...

Comment: Still the Same effect the Listener calls himself.

Comment: Can you post updated code? Extra points for a sandbox!